# How can I limit a query's results to 0 in Drupal 8's hook_views_pre_execute?

Tags: php, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am developing a Drupal 8 website where I have a block view displayed for certain content types that shows related information from other content types. I need to dynamically limit query results based on the moderation state of the node being visited (as opposed to the content in the view). My plan was to grab the node's moderation state from the page context and use that to limit the results of the view. However, the setLimit function seems to have no effect on query results:

```php
function myModule_views_pre_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
  // Only for my_view view.
  if ($view->id() == 'my_view') {
    $list_node = Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    if($list_node->moderation_state->value == "approved"){

    }else{
      dpm("node is not approved, setting limit to 0");
      $view->query->setLimit(0);
    }   
  }
```

I've seen [similar questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185977/alter-views-limit-using-hook-views-query-alter) asked a couple years ago, but the answers seemed to point to altering the pager instead of the query... it seems strange that the pager would somehow be tied directly to the sql query itself and not just to the display or marshaling of the results. Does the setLimit function not simply edit the "LIMIT" part of the eventual sql query? Or is the pager actually altering the limit after my code runs? Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 9.11.2020**

I played around with trying different things in different hooks, inspecting the actual query generated via the view editing interface, as this exposes the "LIMIT #" expression. I learned 2 main things from that process:

1. Things can and will edit the query in other hooks. I found that putting the setLimit in `hook_views_query_alter` got overridden by some other module, and by the time `hook_views_pre_execute` came around, it would be changed from what I set it to earlier. However setting it in `pre_execute` is working fine.
2. Amazingly, calling `setLimit(0)` **removes the LIMIT expression from the query entirely!** However, any other value seems to work fine.

Is this expected behavior? Does Drupal prohibit setting the limit for a query to 0? Or should I be logging an issue somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x) instead.

```php
function myModule_views_pre_execute(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  // Only for my_view view.
  if ($view->id() == 'my_view') {
    $list_node = Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    if($list_node->moderation_state->value == "approved"){

    }else{
      dpm("node is not approved, setting limit to 0");
      $query->setLimit(0);
    }   
  }
```

Comment: I started out trying hook_views_query_alter, eventually moving to `hook_views_pre_execute` as I thought maybe something else was editing the query after me. However this did not work either. The only way I've found to mask the results is by doing `$view->result = []` in `hook_views_post_execute`, however I would like to avoid this option as the query may be expensive and there is no need to run it if it is being masked

Comment: You should first try [Configure Views for debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/configure-views-for-debugging) and show the actual SQL query. That way you'd be better off in checking the resulting query.

Comment: If there is indeed some other module modified the view query after you, try to delay your hook by [setting a larger module weight](https://x-team.com/blog/changing-the-order-of-hooks-in-drupal/).

Comment: ah, good idea. Turns out that yes, something is editing the query after my query_alter is called. However, if I put the `setLimit` in pre_execute, the change seems to take, BUT something very interesting is happening - when I do `setLimit(0)`, it removes the "LIMIT" expression from the query entirely! However, if I do `setLimit(1)`, I can see the "LIMIT 1" expression in the query and it limits the results. Is this a bug, or intended behavior? Effectively I want the query not to run at all, is there a better way of accomplishing that?

Comment: It's probablely by design. I couldn't find proper documentation about it, but I guess the `QueryInterface::range()` implementation used properly treats 0 the same as NULL. It's understandable because if people want 0 items, they'd better off not doing the query at all. Perhaps instead of `setLimit()`, you can add a condition that would always be FALSE?

Comment: It seems very odd that this is by design, since it is quite common AFAIK to do this since a DBMS like mysql will optimize away the query, making it a very efficient way to mask results. I ended up using a suggestion provided in the [Drupal stack exchange version of my question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296638/how-can-i-limit-query-results-in-hook-views-pre-execute/296665#296665) where you can set some properties of the view object in `query_alter` and that seems to work. However, this behavior seems like a security flaw in places where results are dynamically limited.